# How do I strip Ubuntu of its Amazon referral code?

Tags: amazon

I finished a fresh install of Ubuntu "Raring" today and noticed the Amazon web app comes bundled with an Amazon Affiliate referral code. I don't wish for this to be there, especially given that it appears to be a violation of the [Associates Program Participation Requirements](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/associates/help/operating/participation?ie=UTF8&pf_rd_i=assoc_operating&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_p=&pf_rd_r=&pf_rd_s=assoc-center-1&pf_rd_t=501&ref_=amb_link_353005802_3).

1. Can I reconfigure the Amazon web app to not include this code?
2. What other referral codes should I expect to stumble upon? Is there a list? And can I remove those too?

Edit:

I'm come to realize two things:

1. "Amazon" is not a web app but rather a web shortcut, that I can delete.
2. Apparently the Canonical/Ubuntu and referral code situation isn't new and received some bad press in the day. I certainly do not wish to re-open any can of worms and am more than happy with this question's closure/deletion.

Comment: Block the web-applet from inside Firefox? Should not be that hard...

Comment: I feel I should note that I have no problem supporting Canonical, but wish it were on my terms not embedded in an inbox application.

Comment: @BrunoPereira Oh, I just realized it's a mere web link that opens in the default browser. If you want to suggest I simply remove the link, I'd be happy to accept it and move on from this slightly embarrassing ordeal. (Although the referral code shipping inbox is still concerning.)

Comment: Its fine, I think your question is valid for the site, I did not upvote it, but did not downvote it also. The issue is that I think that you are confusing something simple to do (disabling the web-applet), and that question is already asked many many more times in other occasions through the site... :)